# Conditionally failing validation using class-validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

Using [conditional validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator#conditional-validation) in the `class-validation` library and the example below, I want the validation to fail if the `woodScrews` property is given a value when the `tool` property is `Tool.TapeMeasure`. I wasn't really able to find anything that does that.

```js
import { IsEnum, IsNumber, Min, ValidateIf } from 'class-validator'

export enum Tool {
  Drill = 'Drill',
  TapeMeasure = 'Tape Measure'
}

export class ToolBox {
  @IsEnum(Tool)
  public tool: Tool;

  @ValidateIf(toolBox => toolBox.tool === Tool.Drill)
  @IsNumber()
  @Min(5)
  public woodScrews?: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That method only works to ignore validations i.e with your dto, you validate that the class ToolBox has a property woodScrews of type number and with a minimun value of 5 only if the property Tool is equals to Drill otherwise you'll ignore the validations.

I'm not sure if you can solve this with class-validator but you can create some customs pipes and apply your own logic.

More info here: https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes

Comment: Was afraid I'd have to implement my own, was hoping to get something out of the box. Thanks.